Spring JPA pagination with sorting by custom function
I am trying to perform a query, sorting (asc or desc) results by another table, where the relationship is 1:N.
I'd like to do something like this (didn't find a simpler way to achieve the same result) in Spring JPA:
select f.* 
from feed f join feed_delivery fd on f.feed_id = fd.feed_id
group by f.feed_id
order by array_agg(fd.delivery_type order by fd.delivery_type desc), f.feed_id 

where array_agg is a PostgreSQL custom function (note that it has some internal sorting arguments).
I registered the PostgreSQL dialect and checked via debugger that the function was loaded (org.hibernate.dialect.function.array.ArrayAggFunction):
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

But don't know how to sort results.
As input I have some filters (that I reduced to Specification) and a Pageable.
I tried something like this:
val pageableToUse =
    PageRequest.of(
        pageable.pageNumber,
        pageable.pageSize,
        Sort.by("array_agg(feedDeliveries_feedDeliveryPK_deliveryType)")
    )
return feedRepository.findAll(filter, pageableToUse)

but fails with: "No property 'array' found for type 'Feed'".
Note: feedDeliveryPK is an EmbeddedId.

Sort.by only accepts entity field names (for JPA).

Sure, that's only pseudo-code.
I see that the implementation of the Hibernate org.hibernate.dialect.function.array.ArrayAggFunction (of hibernate-core) handles it but don't know how to use/invoke it.

As stated you cannot as Sort.by only accepts entity field names not JPA clauses. If you want this write the query.

Ok, I rewrote using criteria api but didn't find a way to set the "order by" inside the function.
The org.hibernate.dialect.function.array.ArrayAggFunction#render method receives a withinGroup parameter that is actually null.
This is what I have done so far:
[val orderByClause: List = listOf(
cb.asc(
cb.function(
"array_agg",
DeliveryType::class.java,
fdPkJoin.get(FeedDeliveryPK::deliveryType.name)
)
),
cb.asc(feed.get(Feed::feedId.name))
)
cq.orderBy(orderByClause)]

Resolved by casting the CriteriaBuilder to HibernateCriteriaBuilder and using the arrayAgg method.
